# Find links in a page with specific xpath that matches may instead of anchor tag

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to find all the links in a page with iPhone when search for iPhone.I have tried getting the XPath with //h3/span[contains(text(),"iPhone")] and this has bought me all the links .I found it by printing it's size.But when I am iterating through for loop like

```
for(Webelemnet link:iphonelinks)
{
driver.findElement(By.xpath(link.toString)).getText();
}
```

It's throwing me with invalidselector exception and //h3/span[contains(text(),'iPhone')] XPath is not a valid xpath

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have found the web element, you do not have to search it again.You can just read the link's text property in the link attribute. Try the below code.

```
for(Webelemnet link:iphonelinks)
{
   link.getText();
}
```

Comment: if this helped, please consider marking this as an accepted answer. Thx